# Spring doesn't see my repository

Tags: spring

Hello I am reading Spring in Action 4th and trying to do example with spring boot instead of clear Spring MVC but now I get error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in pl.lukasz.sppiter.SppiterController required a bean of type 'pl.lukasz.sppiter.SppiterRepository' that could not be found.
>   Action: Consider defining a bean of type 'pl.lukasz.sppiter.SppiterRepository' in your configuration.

I tryed to add @Repository and scanBasePackages but it not helping.

```
public interface SppiterRepository{

List<Sppiter> findSppiters(long max, int count);}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sppiters")
public class SppiterController {
private SppiterRepository sppiterRepository;
@Autowired
public SppiterController(SppiterRepository sppiterRepository) {
   this.sppiterRepository = sppiterRepository;
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Sppiter> sppiters() {
   return sppiterRepository.findSppiters(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface should inherit from one of the base interfaces such as `Repository`, `CrudRepository`, `PagingAndSortingRepository` etc

Update your interface to be:

```
public interface SppiterRepository extends Repository<Sppiter, Long>
```